# I can't get full list after processing Spring Data JPA query ,It shows only first item

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a Spring Data JPA repository with following method

```
@Repository
public interface ResultAnalysisRepository extends CrudRepository<ResultAnalysis, Long>
{
    @Query(value ="select new com.eduticanew.model.LatestResultDstrbtn(e.subject, e.achivedPer,(e.achivedPer/sum(e.achivedPer))*100) from ResultAnalysis e where e.examID = ?1")
    List<LatestResultDstrbtn> findResultByLatestAchivedPer(String exmName);
}
```

here, query calls constructor of bean class ..,while processing I get only a first item as list,like this

[image: result of this query]

but i want list like

[[image: Required output][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dorLD.png)

this is the constructor in that query, problem is in third parameter

`LatestResultDstrbtn(e.subject, e.achivedPer,(e.achivedPer/sum(e.achivedPer))*100)`

is there any mistakes,i'm new in programming anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by changing code like,

```
@Query(value ="select new com.eduticanew.model.LatestResultDstrbtn(e.subject, e.achivedPer,(e.achivedPer/(select sum(e.achivedPer) from ResultAnalysis e where e.examID = ?1))*100) from ResultAnalysis e where e.examID = ?1")
List<LatestResultDstrbtn> findResultByLatestAchivedPer(String exmName);
```